# Find Circum Center of Three point of Triangle [Not using Compass]

Tags: math, geometry

I am trying to find **circumcenter** of Given Three point of Triangle……..

**NOTE: all these three points are with X,Y and Z Co-Ordinate Means points are in 3D**

I know that the circumcenter is the point where the right bisectors intersect….

But for that I have to find middle point of each side then the right bisectors and then intersection point of that …..this is long and error some  process……

**Is there not any formula** which just takes as input these three points of triangle and giving us the **Circumcenter of Triangle ……?**

Thanks………

Comment: sorry, couldn't do any better, it no ordinary homework for sure, i think i will take more time, i will also try go get help from http://math.stackexahnge.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wiki page on [Circumscribed circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle) has it in terms of [dot and cross products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#Barycentric_coordinates_from_cross-_and_dot-products) of the three vertex vectors. It also has a formula for the radius of the circle, if you are so interested.

Comment: its good.....but is there not any numerical example? i think vector algebra is very error some.........for calculation....

Comment: @Pritesh: I don't see how you can avoid those computations. The only numerical problem might be taking the magnitude of a vector, which will correspond to taking square roots in other methods. You will have the same issues. Dot and cross products are only addition and multiplication. As to division, you will get that in other methods too. Did you try it out?

Comment: @Moron , Ya i have tried it out.....but i looking for some solution which do't contain vector , dot product and cross product and etc...Thanks......

Comment: @Moron, after long thinking and get experiment with different-different think......i have decided to going with this solution......which you have suggested http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#Barycentric_coordinates_from_cross-_and_dot-products

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to make sure that points are not collinear. i.e. do not lie in the same line. For that you need to find the direction cosines of the lines made by three points, and if they have same direction cosines, halt, you can't get circle out of it.

For direction cosine please check [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_cosine) on wikipedia.

(A way of finding coordinate-geometry and geometry -- based on the theorem that, a perpendicular line from center of circle bisects a chord)

1. Find the equation of the plane.

   [image: equation of the plane]

   This equation must reduce to the form

   [image]

   and the direction cosines (of the line perpendicular to plane determines the plane), so direction cosines of the line perpendicular to this line is

   given by this [**link**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Plane.html) equations -- 8,9,10 (except replace it for `l`, `m`, `n`).
2. Find the equation of the lines (all three) in 3-d
   `(x-x1)/l=(y-y1)/m=(z-z1)/n` (in terms of direction cosines) or
   `(x-x1)/(x2-x1)=(y-y1)/(y2-y1)=(z-z1)/(z2-z1)`
3. Now we need to find the equation of line

   a) this perpendicular to the line, from 2 (let `l1, m1, n1` be direction cosines of  this line)

   b) must be contained in place from 1 (let `l2, m2, n2` be direction cosines of  this line perpendicular to plane)
4. Find and solve (at least two lines) from `3`, sure you will be able to find the center of the circle.
5. How to find out equation ??? as we are finding the circum-center, we will get our points (i.e. it is the midpoint of the two points) and for a) we have

   `l1*l+m1*m+n1*n = 0` and `l2*l+m2*m+n2*n = 0` where l, m, n are direction cosines of our, line, now solving this two equation,  we can get `l`, `m`  interms of `n`. And we use this found out `(x1,y1,z1)` and the value of `l, m, 1` and we will have out equation.

The other process is to solve the equation given in this equation

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725871/solving-the-multiple-math-equations

Which is the deadliest way.

The other method is using the advantage of computer(by iteration) - as I call it (but for this you need to know the range of the coordinates and it consumes lot of memory)

it's like this (You can make it more precise by incrementing at 1/10) but certainly bad way.

```
for(i=minXrange, i>=maxXrange; i++){
  for(j=minYrange, j>=maxYrange; j++){
    for(i=minZrange, i>=maxZrange; k++){
      if(((x1-i)^2 + (y1-j)^2 + (z1-k)^2) == (x2-i)^2 + (y2-j)^2 + (z2-k)^2) == for z)){
        return [i, j, k];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ya but it should be good if.....all this thing comes in just a single formula........

Comment: Ok thank you so much.....I have already got one excellent solution from you......of my last question.....Thanks...