# How to calculate the smallest enclosing circle ( center and radius ) of multiple latitudes and longitudes

Tags: c#, geolocation, geometry, latitude-longitude

I'm looking for a C# formula to find the Center Point and Radius of the smallest enclosing circle which contains all my GeoPoints ( List of Lat and Lng )

[image: Sample of circles I'm looking for]

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739777/sphere-that-surely-encompass-given-list-of-points-points-are-with-x-y-and-z-co which links to specific algorithms

Comment: Is your underlying surface a sphere or an ellipsoid (the geoid)? Are you looking for "circles" on the surface? Or are the circles just Euclidean circles in the lat / long coordinate plane?